# Convert days to years and days remaining

Tags: php

I am trying to convert days to Number of years and Days Remaining format. This is what I tried:

```
<?php
$reg_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($whois_details[5])); // 1997-09-15
$total_days = (date('Y-m-d') - $reg_date) * 365; // 2014-07-30
$total_years = intval($total_days / 365);
$remaining_days = ($total_days % 365) % 30;
if ($total_days < 365) {
    $remaining_days = $total_days;
}
echo $total_years.' years and '.$remaining_days.' days';
?>
```

OUTPUT - for 300

```
0 years and 300 days - THIS IS OK
```

OUTPUT - for 500

```
1 years and 15 days - THIS IS NOT OK
```

http://codepad.org/MDQjsz5l

SHOULD BE - for 500

```
1 years and 135 days
```

What am I mistaking. I checked the C sharp question and tried converting it.

Comment: Why mod 365 and then mod 30?

Comment: This was the formula I found in the C# question

Comment: I'm assuming you're ignoring leap years?

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm that would be much complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why the code you copied does what it does, can you link it?

This of course ignores the intricacies of dates (like leap-years), but works as an example of how this algorithm typically works. To account for leap-year, you'd need to know if the timespan in question included any. If all you're given is a number of days, this is about the best you can do.

```
$days = 500;
$years_remaining = intval($days / 365); //divide by 365 and throw away the remainder
$days_remaining = $days % 365;          //divide by 365 and *return* the remainder
```

Comment: it seams that it sends the expected result. Will try to check on it and link it, anyway, it was c#, maybe has different functions.

Comment: C# mod operator works the same as PHP. I think the c-sharp version was likely -calculating-estimating years, months, then days remaining.

Comment: I have added the timespan with dates ($reg_date), could you also let me know a version with leap-years based on my current code.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate StackOverflow question so it gets more visibility. I'd be interested in the answer; I don't have a solution off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using the date functions in PHP if you want to consider leap-years.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-07-30');
$date2 = new DateTime('1997-09-15');

$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $interval->format('%Y years, %m months, %d days');
```

or for your question

```
$years = $interval->format('%Y');// total years
$days = $interval->format('%a') - (int)$years*365;// total days - total years * days per year
```

But I believe the above 2 lines could be done in a more date function way.

Comment: Thanks, yes, found out.